# Specifying row font for just one row in tabu while keeping global line separation

Tags: tabu

I want to achieve a table with:
1. a global tabulinesep
2. the left column in bold
3. The top row bold, white and a red panel
However when I add rowfont the tabulinesep breaks down.
How do I do this?

Preamble

```
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{tabu} 
\global\tabulinesep=3mm %Minimal vertical space in tables
```

Main

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabu}[X]{|>{\bfseries}X[4]|X[2c]|X[4]|}
    \everyrow{\hline}
    \rowcolor{red}
    \rowfont{\color{white}\bfseries}
    text & text & text \\
    text & text & text \\
    text & text & text \\
    text & text & text \\
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Can you draw a simple paint example what the result shall be? So it's more easy to understand. And please insert 4 spaces before end table. I can't to that, because minimum change is 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=1mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {|X[4]|X[2,c]|X[4]|},
    row{1} = {bg=red3, fg=white, font=\bfseries},
    column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    hlines,
  }
    text & text & text \\
    text & text & text \\
    text & text & text \\
    text & text & text \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]